# Product of Orthogonal Projection Matrices with Positive Semidefinite Matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

I recently came across this following claim about projection matrices, which I am unsure it is true. However, I cannot seem to find a valid counterexample.

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ be a full column rank rectangular matrix where $k<n$. Define the projection matrix $P_U=U(U^TU)^{-1}U^T$. Now let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive semidefinite matrix of rank $k<n$. The claim is that if both $MP_U$ and $(I-P_U)M$ are nonzero, then
$$
(I-P_U)MP_U \neq \mathbf{0}.
$$

The claim is clearly false if we allow $k=n$ as $M=I$ would be a valid counterexample. However, I can't seem to come up with a valid counterexample for $k<n$.

Appreciate any ideas/thoughts on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true. Counterexample: let $n=4,\,k=2$ and
$$
U=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1\\ 0&0\\ 0&0},
\ P_U=\pmatrix{1\\ &1\\ &&0\\ &&&0},
\ M=\pmatrix{0\\ &1\\ &&1\\ &&&0}.
$$
Then $(I-P_U)M=\operatorname{diag}(0,0,1,0)\ne0$ and $MP_U=\operatorname{diag}(0,1,0,0)\ne0$ but $(I-P_U)MP_U=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $P_U$ is symmetric , and positive semidefinite because its eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. Then $M=P_U$ will be a perfect counterexample.